# Path of file(located in desktop) for firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase storage for android. Just so I could learn it, I tried to upload a jpg image from my desktop to the firebase storage. I am attaching my code. The error says directory not found. Can somebody explain how to fetch the image from my desktop correctly?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Storage is intended for Android devices only, thus, the URI (and the file) must live on the Android device. URIs on the file system won't be accepted.

Comment: Thanks ! Can I manually upload images to my storage database? The "Upload Files" button isnt working when I click on it, even though I have changed the read and write rules to "true".

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? When you say "not working" can you describe what that means (nothing happens, file picker appears but nothing uploads, errors in the console, etc.)? You can also drag files from your computer onto your android emulator and reference them that way. See our presentation at Google I/O: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE and the sample code: https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c

Comment: I am using Google chrome on Windows 8.1. When I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Happen to know if it's Chrome 51? If so, this is a known issue and it's a bug with Chrome that we can't easily work around. I would recommend using a different version of Chrome, or trying Firefox/Edge.